# Why does my Neural Network return the same output for different inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am programming a neural network to test an idea i have. Problem is i haven't even been able to test how well the network performs because it keeps putting out the exact same output no matter the input.

The network is being trained with the MNIST data set, and has 10 output nodes.

Simply due to how neural networks calculate maths, even if the neural network wasn't converging on anything, it still wouldn't make any mathematical sense that it would put out the exact same output down to the millionths decimal place.

Whenever i retrain the network it of course has a new output, likely due to the new set of calculated weights. But that output then remains the same, no matter the input.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Edit:

I'm using a sigmoid function.

After i train it, and query it my output looks something like this.

```
`array([[ 0.10651613],
   [ 0.11501053],
   [ 0.11034159],
   [ 0.11213908],
   [ 0.10754446],
   [ 0.09952921],
   [ 0.10827382],
   [ 0.11763775],
   [ 0.10538466],
   [ 0.10562691]])
```

Then i will query it with a different input, and will get the same exact output.

Comment: It depends. You haven't given any information on the structure of your network, the activation, or the output. Also, I'll take a shot in the dark but you're probably encountering an exploding gradient.

Comment: I'm using a sigmoid function.

After i train it, and query it my output looks something like this.

array([[ 0.10651613],
       [ 0.11501053],
       [ 0.11034159],
       [ 0.11213908],
       [ 0.10754446],
       [ 0.09952921],
       [ 0.10827382],
       [ 0.11763775],
       [ 0.10538466],
       [ 0.10562691]])

Then i will query it with a different input, and will get the same exact output.

Comment: I do have a couple of ideas as to the problem and potential solution. But It is impossible to tell for sure without any code. :)

Comment: I just did more research on exploding gradients and found this: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap5.html

After reading through the first paragraph, i think it's deeply relevant to my problem, and is likely putting me on the right track to solving it. 

Thanks for the tip! I'll let you know if i end up solving it.

Comment: (just saw your next message) 

Yes  understand your point and figured this problem might come up. The problem is i am hesitant to post my code online as i think the idea i have has the potential to be really valuable, and i' don't want to risk someone taking credit for it.

Comment: Uh, okay. Try this: If x is your data... `x = x.astype(bool).astype(np.int32)`. Now, retrain your system. You should also consider using relu as your activation.

Comment: I tried it but the same problem still occurs. When you say data you mean my input data correct? I'm using the MNIST data set. So each input is an array of 784 numbers representing an image. I wrote it like this.    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
inputs = inputs.astype(bool).astype(numpy.int32)

Comment: Posted an answer, because it was too long for a comment. Let me know how the changes go.